# where to get training data for SVM for facial expression recognition?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

I am working on a project where I have to detect a face and extract an expression out of it to do some processing on the expression afterwards, I have used [CI2CV face sdk](http://face.ci2cv.net/) to do the detection and landmarks extraction, using an image such as this

[image: face with landmarks on it]

i managed to write the output in a file:

`n_points: 66
{
54.9274 129.935
56.0976 142.037
58.2824 153.995
61.554  165.839
65.8937 177.512
.
.
.
}`

How can I train SVM to get the expression? and where can I get training data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one [The UNBC-McMaster Shoulder Pain Expression Archive Database](http://www.consortium.ri.cmu.edu/painagree/).